# Adding .HTML extension to Codeigniter pages

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to add .html extensions to every post page slug in Codeigniter? My current page URL looks like http://blog.localhost/news/first_post

News is the category name, and first_post is the post name. I want first_post to end in .html, like http://blog.localhost/news/first_post.html

How can I achieve that if I currently have no extension shown in my URL?

Thanks!

Comment: you need rewrite rule in server (Apache, Nginx)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set url suffix on your config.php

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

Comment: Nice, just what I was looking for +1

Comment: how can i change a specific page url like `contact.php` to `contact.xml` instead of all pages  ?

Comment: Hello @HamzaZafeer, you can add a dedicated route in the routes.php file like this 
```$route['contact.php'] = 'contact_controller_name';```